# Elastic search date range aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Json Data

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "deleted-connector",
            "_id": "AHkuN5_iRGO-R5dtaOvz6w",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "user_id": "1a9d05586a8dc3f29b4c8147997391f9",
               "deleted_date": "2014-08-02T04:55:04.509Z"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "deleted-connector",
            "_id": "Busk7MDFQ4emtL3x5AQyZA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "user_id": "1a9d05586a8dc3f29b4c8147997391f9",
               "deleted_date": "2014-08-02T04:58:31.440Z"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "outboxprov1",
            "_type": "deleted-connector",
            "_id": "4AN0zKe9SaSF1trz1IixfA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "user_id": "1a9d05586a8dc3f29b4c8147997391f9",
               "deleted_date": "2014-07-02T04:53:07.010Z"
            }
         }
]
```

Am trying to write aggregation query which will find records in particular "deleted_date" range. 
This is my query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_team": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "deleted_date",
         "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "2014-08-02"
          },
          {
            "to": "2014-08-02"
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "daily_team_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is am not getting correct number of records in particular date range. When i put any date am getting some doc_count number. Am new to elastic search. Am not sure is it the way to write range aggregation query. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think problem is you are confused with "from" and "to" of date range aggregation, with range filter. Range filter includes both date (from and to ) in default. But in date_range aggregation, includes the from value and excludes the to value for each range..

In your query,

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_team": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "deleted_date",
         "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "2014-08-02"
          },
          {
            **"to": "2014-08-02"** -- > if you want to include 2014-08-02 date then do,
              "to" : "2014-08-03" (increase date by one, so 08-02 is included) 
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "daily_team_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This was also encountered by me, and I think your problem is also same.

FYI, look at the [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html).

Answer (score 1):

What OP is looking for is `InternalDateRange` query. Try this instead:

```
 {
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "daily_team": {
      "date_range": {
        "field": "deleted_date",
        "format": "YYYY-MM-DD",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "from": "2014-08-02||/d",   // /d rounds off to day
                                        // from value -> 2014-08-02T00:00:00.000Z
            "to": "2014-08-03||/d"      // to value -> 2014-08-03T00:00:00.000Z
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "daily_team_count": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return count of matching results in single bucket named `daily_team`.

```
"buckets": [
           {
              "key": "2014-08-02T00:00:00.000Z-2014-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
              "from": 1470096000000,    //test data value
              "from_as_string": "2014-08-02T00:00:00.000Z",
              "to": 1470182400000,      //test data value
              "to_as_string": "2014-08-03T00:00:00.000Z",
              "doc_count": 0
           }
        ]
```

This will return single bucket containing matching `doc_count`.

```
"ranges": [
      {
        "from": "2014-08-02"
      },
      {
        "to": "2014-08-02"                
      }
```

Using above ranges will return 2 buckets, one each for `from` and `to` date range.

`from -> 2014-08-02-*
 to   -> *-2014-08-02` as shown on [official documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html).